# Select2 empty icon span

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-select2

How to remove icon dropdown in the red circle. I'm using tag Select then using JavaScript `Select2`. I'm using it like this:

```
$('.select2').select2();

<select id="select" class="select2"></select>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can remove the arrow with css

```
.select2-selection__arrow {
    display:none;
}
```

You can see my jsfiddle showing it here:
https://jsfiddle.net/7ouzLjtr/1/